# How can I view the style attributes of a div in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am using

```
console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++", document.getElementById("liqcont").attributes);
```

before the `return{}` part of a .tsx file.

Typescript is returning an error

> TS2531: Object is possibly null.

I need the style properties of the liqcont div to see what class properties have been actually rendered. Any other way to do that?

Comment: react is just a bad idea :D

Comment: Did you try with refs?

Comment: I haven't tried with refs. Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using refs, and then in componentDidMount get all attributes of that element with the ref. Something like this should work :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
     let attributes = this.refs["wrapper"].attributes;
    }


    render(){
        return (
           <div ref="wrapper">
             ........
           </div>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Error message - 'TS2339 : Property 'attributes' does not exist on type 'ReactInstance' @boky